# Bitmap to SVG Programmatically conversion

Tags: android, bitmap, svg

How can we convert bitmap to SVG programmatically in Android?

[SVG Library for android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/)

This library is used to manipulate SVG file.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? did you find a library?

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert a raster based image to a vector based image, as the underlying data is completely different, you can read a bit more about the differences on Wikipedia for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics
'Converting' between the two are not a possibility, but there are different algorithms for approximating a conversion. Many programs used for vector drawing (e.g. adobe illustrator or incscape) have options for auto-tracing i.e. fitting vectors to a raster image to get a close result to the original.

In your case, you will either have to come up with your own tracing algorithm, or have a pre-made svg file that you load using the library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **raster-to-vector** (*vectorization*) library such as **[potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)** or **[autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/)**, and create an Android **[native library](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)** out of it.

Unfortunately I do not know any such vectorization library entierely made in Java, which would have made the port to Android simpler.

You have to check if the libraries I mentionned above can be **easily adapted** to native android code (for example, they have to cross-compile to an ARM architecture; you may have dependencies issues too).

Answer (score 1):

see the Potrace:
http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

> Potrace(TM) is a tool for tracing a bitmap, which means, transforming a bitmap into a smooth, scalable image. The input is a bitmap (PBM, PGM, PPM, or BMP format), and the default output is an encapsulated PostScript file (EPS).

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192). If the tool or library is not free-to-use, please also mention this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**`potrace`** is the tool for that. You can process them bulk, but first you have to convert the images to monochrome:

```
ls ./p*.jpg | xargs -L1 -I {}  convert -monochrome {} {}.bmp
ls -1 ./*.bmp | xargs -L1 -I {} potrace {} -r 300 -b svg -o {}.svg
```

You could do a simple web-service where you convert any image you upload.

There also an android project that tries to bring potrace on android and you could see how it does that or maybe even use it:
https://github.com/jiangpeng79/antrace

Install on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install potrace
```

Raster-to-vector (vectorization) works only on monochrome images. If you want to convert images that are not monochrome, `Inkscape` has a tracer tool base on potrace that support multiple colors, it first converts the image to color layers and then it trace those and combines the result. Unfortunately it doesn't have a command line for that feature yet but you can see how it works:

> To use the tracer, load or import an image, select it, and select the
>   **Path** > **Trace Bitmap** item, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B.</kbd>

See

[Tutorial here!](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.en.html)